# Janusgraph 4.0 composite index from Java app does not work

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I am building my index like that:

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("conf/janusgraph-cql-es-server.properties")

final JanusGraphManagement mt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey key = indexManagement.getPropertyKey("myID");
mt.buildIndex("byID", Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex();
mt.commit();

ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph,"byID").call();
...
final JanusGraphManagement updateMt = graph.openManagement();
updateMt.updateIndex(updateMt.getGraphIndex("byID"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
updateMt.commit();
```

But when I call:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("myID", "100");
```

I get a full scan, that returns a correct result:

```
o.j.g.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx   : Query requires iterating over all vertices [(myID = 100)]. For better performance, use indexes
```

Also if I print the schema I have:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vertex Index Name              | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
byID                           | Composite   | false     | internalindex  | myID:    INSTALLED |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edge Index (VCI) Name          | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Relation Index                 | Type        | Direction | Sort Key       | Order    |     Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also looking at the backing it says internalindex, I wonder if I misconfigured something.

edit: 
There were 2 problems.

- The index was Installed not Ready.
- For string properties you also need to do:

```
mgmt.buildIndex('byID', Vertex.class).addKey(ID, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter())...
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark but looks like you not creating the PropertyKey `myID` before trying to use it.

Try something like:

```
final JanusGraphManagement mt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey key = indexManagement.getPropertyKey("myID");
if(key == null) {
    key = mt.makePropertyKey("myID").dataType(String.class).make();
}
mt.buildIndex("byID", Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex();
mt.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem was that the Index was not at Ready state, it was stuck at Install. What I did was to recreate the schema from scratch and in the same management transaction to add the indexes,